# how to get the source page which request other page in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have a form

```
<form name=frmMain method="POST"  action="processUpload.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p align="center"><table border="1" align="center" width="90%" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black">
<tr>
<td width="261" height="111">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0px"  bordercolor="#B9B9B9" id="AutoNumber1" style="border-collapse: collapse" cellpadding="0px" align="left" width="100%" height="114">
    <tr>
        <td width="264" height="25" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FCDCA0">
<p align="left"><b><font face="Tahoma" size="2">&nbsp;</font><font face="Tahoma">Upload you excel file</font></b></p>

 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="15px" height="23">
            <p align="right"  style="vertical-align: middle"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>&nbsp;File:&nbsp;</b></font>&nbsp; </td>
        <td width="300px" height="23">

            <p align="left">&nbsp;<input type="file" name="excelfile" size="40" >
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="15px" height="28">

                <p align="center"></td>
        <td  height="28">
                <p align="left">
                <input type="submit" name="process" value="Process">
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
            </form>
```

I submit this form to prcessUpload.jsp
in processUpload.jsp I do upload file, when upload file is finished, I want to redirect to source page which contains the form.

Problem: I want to make this processUpload.jsp generic, means I will reuse it in other web application. whatever page make a request to this jsp page, I will have the exact name of the source page.

any suggestions or solutions. Thanks in advance.

NathanPhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a hidden argument to the URL in the form that tells the `uploadFile.jsp` where to go back to when it is done.  You'd need to add a button or some javascript to the `uploadFile` page to make this happen at the appropriate time.

Another option would be for the JSP to pick up the redirect location from some a server-side configuration file; e.g. via the servlet context parameters.